# html form elements vs php functions for form element

Tags: php, html, forms

I am using an open source PHP ERP Application. I found something new over there. The application uses different methods for form elements ex : Instead of below

```
<input id="employee_name" class="textfield employee_name" type="text" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" placeholder="" size="20" maxlength="256" value="Eric Stock" name="employee_name[]">
```

I see a php function (method actually) like

```
<?php $f->text_field_d() ?>
```

The application is quite big and I guess would have 300/400 forms and there are single forms which contains 100 + such input/select/check box element.

So, my question is

1. Is this standard in PHP to use some functions/instead of actual HTML
2. Does it impact the performance ; I plan to do some customization so should I use plain text or use these kind of functions

Comment: The PHP would output HTML and no, in this case it wouldn't really impact performance.

Comment: Well, since you're talking about PHP it is strictly related to the server-side, therefore I don't see any other benefit apart from a "cleaner" (or shorter) code, but No, I don't think it will impact in any way the performance. Also, it depends on how big the project is supposed to become, but it won't impact the performance at all in any case.

Comment: lists need an empty line before them to format properly. "Thanks" is considered to be implied and is thus left off questions, or removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not necessarily standard. It's how much do want to re-write the same code over again. The parameter would just be passed to the php function, and the function will do the rest. It doesn't impact performance.

Comment: Thanks...So, can I conclude that calling 100 PHP functions in a page doesnt have any performance impact compared to not a calling any function and writing simple HTML...

Comment: There a few methods for this kind of madness. If the application is designed to display results from a database, I would say YES, PHP would be the standard for displaying those results, especially in HTML format (like a table).